Recognizing numbers in a screenshot using tesseract in python
I am writing a program aimed at recognizing numbers on a screenshot and filling an array with them. Generally, the program works well, but sometimes problems occur: ones either are not recognized or are recognized as fours. I am attaching the program code and the script execution result, where you can see that the number 100,000 was recognized as 00000. I have tried using different --oem and --psm parameters, but the errors persist in any case.
import cv2
import pytesseract
import re
import pyautogui
import numpy as np

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

def screen():
    screen_for_array = pyautogui.screenshot()         
    screen = np.array(screen_for_array)               
    screen = cv2.cvtColor(screen, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)    
    return screen

def recognize_numbers(image, x, y, w, h):
    roi = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
    cv2.imshow('Image', gray)
    cv2.waitKey(0)  
    cv2.destroyAllWindows() 
    
    custom_config = r'--oem 3 --psm 6 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789'
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(gray, config=custom_config)


    numbers = re.findall(r'\d+', text)
    
    return numbers


image_path = screen()
x, y, w, h = 333, 380, 90, 344
numbers = recognize_numbers(image_path, x, y, w, h)
print("number recognition:", numbers)

Using this screenshot, recognition result is as follows: ['95000', '97000', '98111', '98123', '99999', '00000', '110000', '120000', '125000', '149990']
By the way, this image is the final version that the program uses for recognition.
I have tried using different --oem and --psm parameters, but the errors persist in any case. I used both the color image of the screenshot and the black-and-white one (which you can see in the attached screenshot).

I am a complete beginner in programming, trying to learn through any available methods: free courses, YouTube, ChatGPT... The code might be poorly written, but this is the best I can do for now.

Because I don't have got your original image, I tried with your provided image:
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
 
img = cv2.imread('column_numbers.png',cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
 
grayImage = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
(thresh, blackAndWhiteImage) = cv2.threshold(grayImage, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# resize image
scale_percent = 160 # percent of original size
width = int(blackAndWhiteImage.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
height = int(blackAndWhiteImage.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
dim = (width, height)
resized = cv2.resize(blackAndWhiteImage, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

# OCR resized Black & White image
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd=r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
custom_config = r'--psm 3 --oem 3' 
tex = pytesseract.image_to_string(resized, config=custom_config)

# write the numbers into a .txt file
with open("Recognized.txt",'w') as f:
    for num in tex.split():
        f.write(num.replace(',','.')+'\n')
        print(num.replace(',','.'))

# Display image
cv2.imshow("Resized", resized)
 
# Save the image
cv2.imwrite("Resized_Image.png", resized)
 
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

Result:
95.000
97.000
98.111
98.123
99.999
100.000
110.000
120.000
125.000
149.950

PS: Instead of replace the comma with dot from the tesseract result, you can also use a whitelist.
